# Shelly device is already owned by another User

Tags: smart-home

IOT device `Shelly Dimmer` could not connect to cloud.

**Error:**

`Device is already owned by another User`

Comment: We'll need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from shelly support is:

> About ""Device is owned from another customer" 
>   3 years ago we never expect to sell so much devices and the unick IDs running out. 
>   All new devices which we manifacturing now using whole MAC address as ID instead last 6 digits. 
>   Everyone who has this issue need to send a message to Dimitar Stanishev or Me, to provide a special firmware which will resolve it (extend ID).
>   Next week this procedure will be made automaticaly from the APP.

See also support channel topic:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/ShellyIoTCommunitySupport/permalink/2552658274833521

Or solution mentioned in:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/ShellyIoTCommunitySupport/permalink/2578113305621351/

According to this you have to flash your shelly with a special firmware. You can do this using the link below (please adapt the IP of your shelly):

> Open this link on your phone using device ip
>   This Is a firmware for conflicting devices on cloud.
>   You ll see a White screen with with code After update.
>   Do a factory reset, don't update until the device run correctly.

http://192.168.0.100/ota?url=http://shelly-api-eu.shelly.cloud/firmware/SHSW-1_patch/switch1_longid.zip

**Attention**

Make sure to select suiteable firmware for your device.

ota-Update für Shelly 1:

http://shelly-api-eu.shelly.cloud/firmware/SHSW-1_patch/switch1_longid.zip

ota-Update für Shelly Plug S:

http://shelly-api-eu.shelly.cloud/firmware/SHPLG-S_patch/plug-s-longid.zip

ota-Update für Shelly Dimmer:

http://shelly-api-eu.shelly.cloud/firmware/longid_patch/dimmer-longid.zip

ota-Update für Shelly H&T:

http://shelly-api-eu.shelly.cloud/firmware/longid_patch/ht-longid.zip

ota-Update für Shelly 2.5:

http://shelly-api-eu.shelly.cloud/firmware/longid_patch/switch25-longid.zip

See also:

https://www.shelly-support.eu/forum/index.php?thread/1762-anweisung-zur-firmware-aktualisierung-bei-id-konflikt/